# Make search results take user to specific tab on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, search, tabs

I have a Wordpress website I'm working on that uses `jQuery` tabs to separate information.

My client has pointed out that when a user uses the internal search and clicks on a result, the link does not take them to the specific tab that the info is on.

For example, if there are posters in tab #3 and the user searches for "posters", the search result link will take them to the correct page, but will have tab #1 open by default.

This makes it difficult for users to find what they're looking for. Is there any solution for this, or will we have to just do away with the tabs?

Here's the barebones code:

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#apps">apps</a></li>
      <li><a href="#features">features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#faqs">faqs</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="apps">
  </div>

  <div id="features">
  </div>

  <div id="faqs">
  </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(function() { jQuery(".tabs").tabs() });</script>
```

Comment: There is really no way to answer this without knowing how you are generating the tabs and seeing some relevant code.

Comment: can you not just hash the tab id in the url, then the page should load with that tab open

Comment: @jmargolisvt The code has been added.

Comment: Here is an example - this url should open the tabs on tab2: https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/default.html#tabs-2

Answer (score 0):

If you know which tab the content is in:

```
// To open the third tab
jQuery('.tabs').tabs('options', 'active', 2);
```

I'd assume that a tab represents a category, so it should be easy enough to pass that to the results page.